# How to display a UINavigationController over another UINavigationController in a UITabBarController?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, ios9

I have a `UITabBarController` which contains a few tabs. One of the tabs has `UINavigationController` with a `UITableViewController` as the root view controller.

On this tab I am trying to display a view over the top of the `UINavigationController` in a modal fashion. However I still want to retain the `UITabBar` view at the bottom once its displayed **modally**.

Is this possible? Maybe displaying **modally** is the wrong thing - I have a feeling I need to **present the view as a popover**, however I'm having trouble with:

1. Displaying the popover
2. Dismissing the popover

Has anyone got any ideas on how this can be achieved?

**Note:** The thing I want to display **modally/as a popover** is a `UINavigationController` with a `UITableView` as the root view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you do *not* want a modal view, because it will be possible to navigate away from it without dismissing (by tapping another tab bar item).

The user interface idiom most suitable is just *pushing* the view controller. You do not have the option of wrapping it into another navigation controller, (or it would be treated like a modal), but you can modify the navigation bar to suit your needs.

For example, to hide the back button you would use

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

Comment: Thanks. I could use push instead, however the reason I was trying to avoid it was because I can't get the back button to disappear. I tried a few different things like setting the navigationItem back button to nil and the left item to nil but that didn't work. I also tried setting the back button to hidden on the navigation item which partially worked such that the arrow was hidden, however the text still showed up (despite setting that to an empty string).

Comment: You hide the back button by setting an attribute in the **controller**:  `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true`